# I can't get Gunslinger Challenge kills to count while in Showdown?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

I'm using an Explosive Pistol, for Showdown, and trying to use the Auto-Crit-lock-on from Showdown to do the Gunslinger Challenge easier.

The challenge being, "Kill enemies with pistols shortly after looking down the sights."

But I can't get such kills to count while in Showdown? Or am I doing something wrong? I'm looking down the sights for an instant, before firing my bullets...

Comment: To give you a toast for my favorite class in BLTPS, bc it feels damn good to step out with a Jakobs Iron and commit law and order, I will check the fandom and other sources on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The poor bullet speed of Torgue gyrojets may be the reason

Citation of the official [fandom](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Showdown_(Nisha)):

> When Showdown is triggered, Nisha will lock on to nearby targets, providing automatic aim. The auto-aim doesn't take into account critical hit locations however, opting instead to target an enemy's 'center mass', unless sighting down the gun sights in which case the critical points are targeted instead. Each time a target is eliminated, a new target is automatically selected. They can also be cycled manually.

Given that, you should be able to score crits in showdown, even with a Torgue pistol that all suffer a minor lack of accurancy, but the recoil reduction boost of **Showdown** should even that out pretty much. A **Thick Slapper** can outdamage an **Ornery Iron** of same level and rarity and performs better against armored enemies, due to the explosive bonus damage and should therefore suit to fulfill this challenge. However **the time between a projectile being fired and it actually hit the target counts against the timespan** in which you can score this challenge. Given the slow travelling speed of the gyrojet projectiles all torgue pistols will suffer from that flaw as the increased bullet speed mod is not available on pistols.

Jakobs guns in general have the highest bullet speed. Vladof, Dahl and Hyperion can also perform well, tho the **Showdown** mechanic works best with Jakobs weapons as the recoil reduction boost would be rendered useless on Dahl and be even contraproductive on Hyperion as it prevents them to increase their gross base accurancy via their *reverse recoil mechanic*

---

**EDIT**

I oversaw that **Showdown** increases bullet speed by 50 % also. However, this may not be sufficient, as 50 % faster than awkwardly slow can still be **too slow**. The timespan between aiming down the sights, firing a shot and giving your target the final blow is indeed *very* short.

Comment: Ooh! That explains why sometimes the challenge doesn't count some kills I do, even outside of Showdown! Wow, sorta knew that Explosives / Gyrojets were slower than regular bullets, but didn't really think about until now!

Comment: Have you ever tried using a **Duurrp!** torgue rocket launcher? These throw the rockets more in an arc than launching them forward and they suffer from a *really* slow speed and a drastic bullet drop too. Only way to make them somehow usable on mid, to long range (without getting blown up thyself) is with the **fidle dee** prefix (faster projectile speed). A **Fidle dee Duurrp!** or a **Fidle dee Nukem** clears of a wide spread even at range. This mod goes also well with Torgue Assault Rifles like a **Rigurous Torpedo** or a **Rigurous KerBlaster** (i used a lot of Torgue in BL2)

Comment: Not really a rocketman. Ammo's too rare. Maybe with Claptrap or someone else with easy Ammo Regen.